# ASP.net MVC best practice to load defaults from database globally one time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-variables, static-variables

I am working on ASP.net MVC for the first time, I am having `page` table where I create dynamic Pages and there are other tables like `contents` where I have other dynamic contents like widgets

the `top menu` and `footer` lies in all the pages of website, so for each action I need to get pages from database and populate `top menu` with dynamic pages and make another query to load some more pages with `where condition` to show some links to page on footer.
to display these link I have to make these queries on each action.
to optimize and clean the code I put these queries in all controller constructors, but still I am not happy, I want to query it one globally at application level and access anywhere.

Please help in which file and how can I query database and how can I put result in global variables so that I can access any where in application (controllers and views)

Comment: What's wrong with filling them from the db each time, have you checked how long the queries take? Are they optimized?

Comment: along with optimization it is also matter of messy/repeating coding blocks in each controller, my ttfb takes 8 sec i hope this can reduce a bit

Comment: It isn't really the controller's job to execute queries, it is meant to orchestrate other classes to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest place is to have some static members on a class, preferably not the controller, and pump in the results of the query on the first call. You can even declare them as [Lazy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.7.2). Using this method would mean they would be refilled on every recycle of the application pool. You can also place them in objects dependency injected, and control their lifetime at a more granular level. There are also third party cache solutions, but I imagine that's overkill.

Comment: thank you @yuny i am new with .net, can you please write some example, i know static class but how and when to populate it `on first call` and secondly how to make it accessible in all controllers and views

Comment: @FakhrAlam Simply crate a class with a `public static Lazy<MyQueryResult> Result = new Lazy<MyQueryResult>(() => myDb.GetQueryResults());` then to call it use `MyClass.Result.Value`. It will execute the first time it's called and keep the value until the application pool recycles.